# Поиск по JSON | MySql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Есть json столбец.

1. Как мне сделать правильный запрос, чтобы узнать, если в массиве ids определенные номер?
2. Как мне добавить/удалить из массива нужное число с помощью mysql?

Пытался разными способами, но ни Json_contains, ни json_extract и т.п. не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Штатные функции не поймут показанный JSON. Зато поймут `{"ids":["1696"]}`.

Comment: @Akina, так тоже пробовал, но ничего не получилось.

Comment: Плохо пробовал. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb607e9dc284fb29a41dc298cc4c9100)

Comment: @Akina, только сейчас заметил, что это работает при select, но при where нет.

Comment: Да отлично всё работает! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db61f17a692e489462f67078001a49ce

Answer (score 0):

выкинуть джейсон, сделать нормальную связанную таблицу
после этого узнавать обычным запросом select, добавлять обычным запросом insert, удалять обычным запросом delete

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users where favorites LIKE %1234%;
```

**Минусы:** будут попадаться и вхождения чисел в айди, к примеру есть записи

1234, и 123 и при поиске второго будут показаны обе записи, ибо есть вхождение в  **123**4 **123**

Лучше прислушаться к ответу многоуважаемого Ипатьева. (не сарказм)